# Asp.Net forms authentication redirects to .../myapp/default.aspx instead of .../myapp/

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

After authentication, asp.net redirects my users to .../myapp/default.aspx instead of .../myapp/

Is there some way of fixing this? I think it's a little ugly not to mention redundant to contain the extra default.aspx on the url.

I've tried putting the following code in my default.aspx.cs page_load function, but it results in a redirect loop because it cannot distinguish whether the user is accessing myapp/ or myapp/default.aspx:

```
if (Request.RawUrl.ToLower().EndsWith("/default.aspx"))
  Response.Redirect("./");
```

Thanks!

Comment: I've also tried adding the following to the forms section in web.config:
defaultUrl="./"

Comment: The web.config setting should be `defaultUrl="~/"` (The tilde signifies "this app's virtual path").

Comment: Did the above work?  If so, let @devstuff know so that he can post this as a solution below and get some points :)

Comment: Rather than trying to handle this yourself in code, have you tried just leaving out the defaultURL completely from your web.config?
<forms loginUrl="login.aspx" timeout="20" />

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using a login control, decide yourself how the redirect will happen.
Use the login control's event (I think it is Authenticate) and:

```
if (Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] != null)  
{  
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage("someuserid", false);  
}  
else  
{  
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("someuserid", false);  
    Response.Redirect("~/SomePage.aspx");  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to fix this is just to remove the defaultUrl attribute from the web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms ... defaultUrl="default.aspx" ... />
</authentication>
```

When you visit www.yourwebsite.com/myapp, the return url will be "/myapp/", and after login, it will redirect back to "/myapp/". If you use the defaultUrl like above, it will redirect to "/myapp/default.aspx". Actually, I experimented with this on the root of the site, but I would think it works the same for subdirectories.

Comment: Does this *really* work? If so, that sounds too good to be true.

Comment: I've confirmed that it works on root paths, but it's a catch-22 on subdirectories. If you have a default.aspx in the sub-directory (and assuming it's setup in IIS as a default page), it changes the ReturnUrl to "/myapp/default.aspx?". If you DON'T have a default.aspx, the ReturnUrl will be "/myapp/" but that will result in a directory listing page after login. :/

Answer (score 0):

You will need to look at the default page that is set up in IIS.

Comment: I am sure it is fine.  In IIS, if you do not specify a page, it will try to serve up your default pages in order of preference.  If you do specify a page, default or not, it will still show that page in the URL.  This is why he is seeing this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no such file like `"./"` to process for a web server. There MUST be a default file which will be served to client. Because nobody wants to type `"blabla.com/index.aspx"` instead of `"blabla.com"`. Your problem is choosing which page to be called as default.

In IIS, right-click to your web site and go for properties.

There is a tab, which contains "Default Page" order. There must be a couple of web pages like "index.htm, default.aspx, etc". Change these filenames' order. The page you want to be called must be at the top.

PS: YOUR Login page and Logged page are same page! So it will be called redundantly!

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding me: my app is set up correctly so that http://blah/myapp/ goes to my default.aspx. I just want authentication to not put the /default.aspx on redundantly when it does its redirects.

Comment: Is that just because of not showing the file name "default.aspx" ?
Because your code is nothing to do with the authentication. You simply say if the URL ends with "default.aspx", then go to "./" which redirects you to same location.

Comment: When he first goes to his site, it does not show the default.aspx in the URL, which is good - default pages are setup correctly.  However, the login.aspx page has a querystring parameter of ?ReturnURL=default.aspx.  Once a user logs in, they are returned to the home page, but default.aspx is in the URL because of this.  This is what the poster is looking to avoid.

Comment: Ok, it is all about avoiding dafault.aspx in URL. Then he should try @devstuff's advice!

Answer (score 0):

It's not a redundant redirect.

Why? Because when you hit / on a web server, the webserver redirects you to /default.aspx anyway. You're just letting IIS do it instead of the authentication mechanism.

-Oisin

Comment: I'd prefer it this way, for the sake of SEO and cleaner URL's.

Comment: SEO? This is not an entry point for search engines - it's a login page.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue.  My login page was default.aspx and when you hit the application, the redirect url was set to /MyApp/.

I think the end result is that I had to rename my login page to soemthing else (login.aspx)